# Find one element, use data, then delete it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my node.js application I'm currently implementing a "Remember Me" functionality. Everything works quite well so far, but I have a problem with mongoose. What I want to do: I have a model named `Token` with this schema:

```
var TokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    token: { type: String },
    uid: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

This is simply a little collection that maps cookie tokens to a UserId. Then I have this function here:

```
function consumeRememberMeToken(token, fn) {
  Token
  .findOne({ 'token': token }, (err, result) => {
    return (result===null)?fn(null, null):fn(null, result.uid);
  })
  .remove();
}
```

What it should do, is this: find the `uid` for a given `token` string and return it (if there is a result). ***But this function should also delete the entry right after returning the `uid`.***

At the moment, the `uid` from the found token `result` gets returned properly, but it (the result Token) does not get deleted from the collection with the above code. I don't understand how to remove it right after getting it and using the retrieved `uid`. I'm completely new to functional programming and I don't understand how and where to delete the token.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `db.collection.findOneAndDelete` It deletes the document and returns the deleted data, quite the reverse of what you are saying but basically serves your purpose. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/) are the details.

Also [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) is the mongoose representation of the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Token.findOne({ 'token': token }, (err, result) => {
   if(err || !result) return fn(err || "error", null);
   else{
      var uid = result.uid;
      result.remove(function(){
         return fn(null, uid);
      });
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work... the uid gets returned but the token does not get deleted. In other words: after running the above, there are now 2 entries with the same *uid* but different token strings in the collection. Each call adds one entry.

Comment: Add error param in remove callback and check it, result.remove(function(error){ console.log(error);